# Change string into datetime then copy data to new table and compare

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have been researching this for a week and still no luck. I have a txt file that loads into 'temploadsi' table via php. The text file will always have old data that is already in the database so I only want the "new" data. My idea was to have a loading table 'temploadsi' and then compare the time stamps and import only "new" data into table 'tempdatasi'. The issue is that the time stamp column is formatted like 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS' and that will not go into the mySQL datetime field. Therefore I have it set as a text field. I would like to convert the text into a datetime field like 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'. I have looked at STR_TO_DATE and DateTime functions but unable to update 'temploadsi'. Can you all help out?

Comment: What does the `24:59:59` mean? That's not a valid time.

Comment: sorry, should be to put HH:MM:SS - I will edit my 1st question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you failing to update the field is because the time of your data is `24:59:59` which is not valid. The maximum time i think is `23:59:59`, so in order to convert that to date, you need to use the following format

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(datetime,'%m/%d/%Y %x:%x:%x'), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
FROM table1
```

[See SQLFiddle Live Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13bf1/3)

So if you wnt to update your field, you can use this query

```
UPDATE tableName
SET your_columnname = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(your_columnname, '%m/%d/%Y %x:%x:%x'), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
```

and this query assumes that your column you are updating has `VARCHAR` datatype.

Comment: can mySQL only go 'down' to seconds for timestamps?  Most other RDBMSs do nanoseconds, at least (6 decimal places!), so `23:59:59` is _not_ the 'maximum' on those platforms.  This is why it's usually best to do _exclusive_ upper-bounds, with things like `< startOfDay`, and to avoid stuff like `BETWEEN`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I made a typo before I edited my post to reflect my time stamps.

  UPDATE tableName
    SET your_columnname = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(your_columnname,     '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') 

work?

Comment: I got it thanks! Just need to figure out how to add the code tags

Answer (score 0):

Something like Str_to_date('12/10/2012 23:59:59','%m/%d/%y %h:%i:%s')

Don't get why you couldn't find this though

[Mysql Help]
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: this will fail, remember that the record has invalid time `24:59:59`